# Justify items in itemize environment

Tags: itemize, justification

I am trying to figure out how to justify the text inside the bullet points, pardon me I am a little new on LaTeX.

My code is the following

```
\documentclass[10pt,letterpaper,onecolumn]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\begin{itemize}
\item \lipsum[1-1]
\item \lipsum[1-1]
\item \lipsum[1-1]
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

[image: This are the bullet points that I have not been able to justify]

Comment: Add `\sloppy` to your preamble.  The problem is that it doesn't know by default how to efficiently hyphenate Latin, so some words overrun the margin.

Comment: It is justified. Just use regular text and not lipsum.

Comment: If you "teach" it to hyphenate Latin, the problem goes away: `\usepackage[latin]{babel}`.  My earlier comment, `\sloppy`, compensates for both narrow margins and poor hyphenation, but is generally not recommended.

Comment: If the language you write in doesn't have a `babel` module, try loading the `microtype` package.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As noted in the comments, the problem is that the lipsum text cannot be hyphenated properly. Assuming you are actually writing your documents in Latin, then you need to load `babel` with the `[latin]` option.

```
\documentclass[10pt,letterpaper,onecolumn]{article}
\usepackage[latin]{babel}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\begin{itemize}
\item \lipsum[1-1]
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

[image: Latin]

Since it's unlikely you're actually writing in Latin, then any text that TeX knows how to hyphenate will be justified automatically. So for example, if we load the `kantlipsum` package, we get proper hyphenation and therefore justification.

```
\documentclass[10pt,letterpaper,onecolumn]{article}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}
\begin{document}
\begin{itemize}
\item \kant[1]
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

[image: Kant]